# Error when trying to compile a .tex file with latexmk

Tags: macos, latex, xcode

I am running macOS Sierra and have XCode installed

```
$ defaults read /var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.Xcode.plist
{
    InstallDate = "2016-09-13 19:36:06 +0000";
    InstallPrefixPath = "/";
    InstallProcessName = storedownloadd;
    PackageFileName = "Xcode.pkg";
    PackageIdentifier = "com.apple.pkg.Xcode";
    PackageVersion = "8.0.0.0.1.1472435881";
}
```

I am trying to compile a .tex file to a pdf using latexmk but am running into an issue with `setgid`.

```
$ latexmk -pdf ~/testFile.tex
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 22 April 2016, version: 4.45.
Insecure dependency in open while running setgid at /Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk line 2722.
```

I have MacTex installed. I even tried re-downloading `latexmk`, but the issue has not been resolved.

I had to re-install everything from scratch when I recently upgraded from El Capitan, but it worked fine before. I am at a loss for what the issue may be. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`setgid` is not a command – it's a *state*; a special file permission along with 'setuid' and 'sticky'.

'setuid' is perhaps better known: if an executable has the 'setuid' bit set, it will always automatically have permissions of the user which owns it, rather than the user which ran it. (For example, that's how `su` and `sudo` are capable of doing root-only actions.)

'setgid' works the same way, except it applies to the *group* which owns the file. In both cases, however, the program needs to be extra careful to only do things it was *designed* to do and avoid being tricked by the user.

The error message – coming from the `perl` interpreter, since `latexmk` is really a Perl script – means that Perl has noticed that it's running with setuid/setgid privileges, and therefore refuses to do certain things as a precaution against carelessly written scripts.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way that I can tell what file has the `setgid` bit set? I tried running `sudo chmod g-s /Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk`, but the same error happens.

Answer (score 0):

As @grawity stated, the issue was that the setgid state was set for some files needed for the `latexmk` script. To find all of the files that had the bit set, I used the command

```
find / -perm -02000 -ls > search_out
```

on OSX. There were a lot of results, but I found one that had to do with Tex.